# Pilas c# Consola

Tags: c#

como puedo hacer para recorer las pilas de mi codigo?

```
public void DesplegarPila()
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese Paga/Hora: ");
            double apu = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Nodo Actual = new Nodo();
            if (Primero != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n *Pago por hora es de {0} Soles",apu);
                while (Actual != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + Actual.Hora * apu); 
                    Actual = Actual.Siguiente; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pila vacia");
            }
        }
```

por ahora estaba usando eso y por lo que veo no funciona, solo imprime 0, por solo imprime un 0, si ingreso mas valores por alguna razon no se muestran

```
public void InsertarNodo()
        {
            Nodo Nuevo = new Nodo();
            Console.Write("Ingrese las Horas hechas: ");
            Nuevo.Hora = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Nuevo.Siguiente = Primero;
            Primero = Nuevo;

            Console.WriteLine("Nodo ingresado");
        }
```

espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *pila*?

Comment: Cambia esto: Nodo Actual = new Nodo(); por esto Nodo Actual = Primero... y se solucionan todos tus problemas ;)... y documenta tu codigo, y vas a entender tu error... que es que Actual siempre es null en la primera vuelta, y por eso nunca entra....

Comment: Sabes q C# tiene la clase Stack, que ya tiene implementado todo lo q te hace falta